# How do I Delete the 5.0.1 OTA Update on my Rooted Nexus 4?

Tags: updates, delete

A while back I rooted my phone with the stock 5.0 image, and was then pestered by the OTA 5.0.1 update that came shortly after.
Research led me to find a way to disable the event listeners that pop the notifications -- FANTASTIC!  This worked for months...

Today, Snapchat decided to reboot my phone (as it regularly does) in a spectacular fashion that included a long vibration while the screen went dark.   Since my phone's come back online, the "System Update Downloaded" notification is sitting at the bottom of my notification tray; something that wasn't there before.

I've dug through my event listeners and confirmed the correct ones are still disabled, but now I'm hunting for a means to delete the downloaded update so as to remove the notification (Hopefully?)...

Most of my search results show the files should be .APK files in the /system/apps folder, but I have a /system/app folder -- no /apps.  Another post mentioned they'd be in the /cache folder --- they are not....

Does anyone know where these OTA Updates are stored on Lollipop 5.0 so I can nuke 'em?

Thanks in advance for your assistance!

Comment: So what is it you want ? 5.0 or 5.0.1 ?

Comment: I'm fine staying with 5.0 --- I don't want to redo everything and set it all back up, which I understand is required in order to update a rooted device.

I want the 5.0.1 downloaded update to be deleted, which I understand will delete the notification.  The "Update Available" notifications are disabled; somehow the update downloaded, and now it's letting me know...  Where is the file, to delete?

Comment: So, turns out disabling the Google Play Services notifications did it...  I was looking for it earlier, but the instructions were different from the articles I was reading.

Comment: OTA is a little different from other .APKs Can be hard to find. Maybe you should go through every folder with the app: ES3 File Explorer ?

Comment: Disabling GP Services Notifications is a brute way to go about it - unless you don't want **any** notifications ? There are apps out there who can clean-up notifications etc. even a background task killer and boosters ;-)

Comment: I totally agree, Pete -- I don't _want_ to disable ALL the notifications for Google Services... Just the "You have an update waiting to be installed" one (which is actually different text).  It seems like deleting the downloaded OTA update _should_ remove the notification, but I don't know what file I'm looking for, and I'm leary on just nuking files willy-nilly.

I figured someone would know something, somewhere... Here's where I posted first.

Comment: So, back to the original question then: 

Does anyone know where these OTA Updates are stored on Lollipop 5.0 so I can nuke 'em?

Comment: What are your comments on my former comment about ES3 File Explorer ?? Anyway, if you want to do **anything** with OTA I still suggest **un**rooting. You can always root it back again. **If** it starts updating to 5.0.1 after unroot don't worry. **Maybe** some settings need to be sat again but then so be it. You can **usually** "rollback" to 5.0 after that operation.

Answer (score 1):

Just download an factory image From :

`https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images`

**Steps :**

> 1.Unlock bootloader
>
> 2.root phone
>
> 3.flash new image
>
> 4.lock Bootloader

[How do I uninstall the Android update 5.0.1 back to 5.0?](http://www.quora.com/How-do-I-uninstall-the-Android-update-5-0-1-back-to-5-0)

hope this helps.

Comment: Not at all helpful, but thanks.  I figured out how to flash the necessary partitions to update to 5.0.1 without losing data, from a rooted OS.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by successfully updating to 5.0.1 without losing my data: http://aaronhastings.me/updating-to-android-5-0-1-on-rooted-nexus-5/